# Hyundai accent rpm 600- 800 at red light

Tags: rpm

When i start my car my rpm fluctuate 600 to 800
Looks like it will turned off but not
Engine is shaking

Comment: Do you have a misfire? Have you checked or had the codes checked?

Comment: Does this only happen when the car is warming up?

Comment: Does the engine do the same or just the speedometer?